# Withdrawal via Safe gnosis

Tags: gnosis-safe, withdrawal

I have https://goerli.beaconcha.in/validator/8f3dfa31e619eb4f5e3aff8f6230962ea461bc4bb13ff5f564b6e93ec90d02a823caa75c5d1dbfa524cfa4c803100773

Would you tell me if there is any chance to unstake / withdrawal via safe wallet?